# Azure Container Service (AKS) kubeconfig file outdated

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, terraform-provider-azure

I am learning about K8s and did setup a release pipeline with a kubectl apply. I've setup the AKS cluster via Terraform and on the first run all seemed fine. Once I destroyed the cluster I reran the pipeline, I get issues which I believe are related to the kubeconfig file mentioned in the exception. I tried the cloud shell etc. to get to the file or reset it but I wasn't succesful. How can I get back to a clean state?

```
2020-12-09T09:08:51.7047177Z ##[section]Starting: kubectl apply
2020-12-09T09:08:51.7482440Z ==============================================================================
2020-12-09T09:08:51.7483217Z Task         : Kubectl
2020-12-09T09:08:51.7483729Z Description  : Deploy, configure, update a Kubernetes cluster in Azure Container Service by running kubectl commands
2020-12-09T09:08:51.7484058Z Version      : 0.177.0
2020-12-09T09:08:51.7484996Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-12-09T09:08:51.7485587Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/kubernetes
2020-12-09T09:08:51.7485955Z ==============================================================================
2020-12-09T09:08:52.7640528Z [command]C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey\bin\kubectl.exe --kubeconfig D:\a\_temp\kubectlTask\1607504932712\config apply -f D:\a\r1\a/medquality-cordapp/k8s
2020-12-09T09:08:54.1555570Z Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup mq-k8s-dfee38f6.hcp.switzerlandnorth.azmk8s.io: no such host
2020-12-09T09:08:54.1798118Z ##[error]The process 'C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey\bin\kubectl.exe' failed with exit code 1
2020-12-09T09:08:54.1853710Z ##[section]Finishing: kubectl apply
```

Update, workflow tasks of the release pipeline:

Initially I get the artifact, clone of the repo containing the k8s yamls, then the stage does a kubectl apply.

````
"workflowTasks": [
                        {
                            "environment": {},
                            "taskId": "cbc316a2-586f-4def-be79-488a1f503564",
                            "version": "0.*",
                            "name": "kubectl apply",
                            "refName": "",
                            "enabled": true,
                            "alwaysRun": false,
                            "continueOnError": false,
                            "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                            "definitionType": null,
                            "overrideInputs": {},
                            "condition": "succeeded()",
                            "inputs": {
                                "kubernetesServiceEndpoint": "82e5971b-9ac6-42c6-ac43-211d2f6b60e4",
                                "namespace": "",
                                "command": "apply",
                                "useConfigurationFile": "false",
                                "configuration": "",
                                "arguments": "-f $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/medquality-cordapp/k8s",
                                "secretType": "dockerRegistry",
                                "secretArguments": "",
                                "containerRegistryType": "Azure Container Registry",
                                "dockerRegistryEndpoint": "",
                                "azureSubscriptionEndpoint": "",
                                "azureContainerRegistry": "",
                                "secretName": "",
                                "forceUpdate": "true",
                                "configMapName": "",
                                "forceUpdateConfigMap": "false",
                                "useConfigMapFile": "false",
                                "configMapFile": "",
                                "configMapArguments": "",
                                "versionOrLocation": "version",
                                "versionSpec": "1.7.0",
                                "checkLatest": "false",
                                "specifyLocation": "",
                                "cwd": "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)",
                                "outputFormat": "json",
                                "kubectlOutput": ""
                            }
                        }
                    ]
    ```
````

Comment: Can you share the pipeline steps and provide more details. Do you fetch the kubeconfig for the newly created cluster in the pipeline itself?

Comment: I've updated the OP, I don't fetch the kubeconfig.

Comment: Kubectl will need information to connect to your new cluster. You will need to fetch the cluster information and update your kubeconfig file with details of the cluster. One of the ways is that you can use the Az CLI task (az aks get-credentials) to update kubeconfig, prior to calling kubectl apply in your pipeline.

Comment: I've used the command which Radek has given in a task before the kubectl apply task, but same issue. Must be still doing something wrong.
`2020-12-09T13:09:44.8926956Z Merged "medquality-aks1-admin" as current context in /home/vsts/.kube/config
2020-12-09T13:09:45.2265525Z [command]/usr/bin/az account clear`

Comment: Are you still getting "Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup mq-k8s-dfee38f6.hcp.switzerlandnorth.azmk8s.io" ? If it is a new error message can you add it here?

Comment: Yes, unforturnately:
`2020-12-09T13:45:16.8862490Z Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup mq-k8s-dfee38f6.hcp.switzerlandnorth.azmk8s.io on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host
2020-12-09T13:45:16.8942741Z ##[error]Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup mq-k8s-dfee38f6.hcp.switzerlandnorth.azmk8s.io on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host`

Comment: Not sure may be the apply is picking up configurations from a different file. Can you try this, lets get the kubeconfig for the cluster to a specific location, some thing like "az aks get-credentials --name $CLUSTERNAME --resource-group $GROUP --file /tmp/kubeconfig" (replace values of resource group and cluster name).  Then before calling kubectl  apply export the KUBECONFIG env variable, "export KUBECONFIG=/tmp/kubeconfig"

Comment: No luck, I've added a shell task and added the inline export statement, before I amended the task to have the kubeconfig written to temp:
`2020-12-09T15:13:47.7967038Z Merged "medquality-aks1" as current context in /tmp/kubeconfig`

Comment: It was the service connection that was stale and pointing at the old fqdn, as I am relatively new to this I wasn't aware but thank you very much Mani for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see you are using `kubernetesServiceEndpoint` as the Service connection type in Kubectl task.

> Once I destroyed the cluster I reran the pipeline, I get issues....

If the cluster was destroyed. The `kubernetesServiceEndpoint` in azure devops is still connected to the origin cluster. Kubectl task which using the origin `kubernetesServiceEndpoint` is still looking for the old cluster. And it will fail with above error, since the old cluster was destroyed.

You can fix this issue by updating the [kubernetesServiceEndpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-kuber) in azure devops with the newly created cluster:

Go to Azure devops **Project settings**-->**Service connections**--> Find your Kubernetes Service connection-->Click **Edit** to update the configuration.

But if your kubernete cluster gets destroyed and recreated frequently. I would suggest using **Azure Resource Manager** as the Service connection type to connect to the cluster in Kubectl task. See below screenshot.

By using `azureSubscriptionEndpoint` and specifying `azureResourceGroup`, if only the cluster's name doesnot change, It doesnot matter how many times the cluster is recreated.

[image]

See document to create an [Azure Resource Manager service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thank you very much Levi! That was it, it wasn't obvious to me that the service connection could be pointing at the old fqdn. Also thank you very much for pointing out the strategical solution for such a case. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you destroy and reprovision AKS cluster the kube API URL and some other things change, but as you found out, nothing updates this automatically on your configured clients.

What I do to get access new and reprovisioned AKS clusters is :

```
az aks get-credentials --subscription <sub> -g <rg> -n <aksname> -a --overwrite
```

Comment: It is not on the client side. I did the aks get-credentials as well locally but the issue occurs on the release pipeline to which I don't provide a kubeconfig.

Comment: Sorry, understand it better now, added it before the kubectl apply task but same issue.

`2020-12-09T13:09:44.8926956Z Merged "medquality-aks1-admin" as current context in /home/vsts/.kube/config
2020-12-09T13:09:45.2265525Z [command]/usr/bin/az account clear`